# toggle visibility multiple divs javascript

Tags: javascript

Afternoon guys, I am hoping you can help me put the finishing touches to this page.  Basically I have four  links - each of which will be linked to a different version of content - that will be displayed in the same 3 divs by way of togglevisibility.  That is to say that onload, the first link’s content will be displayed (in the three divs) and then the aim is that when another of the four links is clicked, the visible content from the open link closes and the clicked link’s content opens instead.  **(One thing I have successfully avoided in the code I have so far - and am eager to avoid in the final model - is toggling the page to empty.  That is to say if link1’s content is displayed and you click on link1 again, the content stays visible and does not simply toggle on and off.)**

Now using the markup below I am oh so close (!) except for the following…

When the page loads the first  link’s content is displayed as I want to be, but whenever you click one of the other 3 links it is only div1’s content that successfully loads while the other two divs become empty.  I have attempted to alter the toggleVisibility coding (quite crudely I know!) so that each of the 4  links are dealt with as follows;

```
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link1div1’); togglevisibility(‘link1div2’);togglevisibility(‘link1div3’);”>Link 1</a>
```

Is there a way to fix this error from within the  link line (above) so that clicking the link loads the corresponding content into all three divs and not just the first?  I am sure it is something simple that I have overlooked or ill-coded!

Thanks very much for your time and advice in advance.

CSS

```
.section {display:none;}

#link1div1 {display:block;}
#link1div2 {display:block;}
#link1div3 {display:block;}
```

HTML

```
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link1div1’); togglevisibility(‘link1div2’);togglevisibility(‘link1div3’);”>Link 1</a> 
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link2div1’); togglevisibility(‘link2div2’);togglevisibility(‘link2div3’);”>Link 2</a>
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link3div1’); togglevisibility(‘link3div2’);togglevisibility(‘link3div3’);”>Link 3</a>
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link4div1’); togglevisibility(‘link4div2’);togglevisibility(‘link4div3’);”>Link 4</a>

<div id=“div1”>
<div id=“link1div1” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link2div1” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link3div1” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link4div1” class=“section”></div>
</div>

<div id=“div2”>
<div id=“link1div2” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link2div2” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link3div2” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link4div2” class=“section”></div>
</div>

<div id=“div3”>
<div id=“link1div3” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link2div3” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link3div3” class=“section”></div>
<div id=“link4div3” class=“section”></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleVisibility(selectedTab) {
     var section = document.getElementsByClassName('section')
     for(var i=0; i<section.length; i++) {
          if(section[i].id == selectedTab) {
                section[i].style.display = 'block';
          } else {
                section[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would minimise the use of `javascript` and do that using `css`, like this:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/obazopE/1/)**

**javascript:**

```js
function clickHandler(lnk) {
    document.getElementById('sections').className = lnk;
    return false;
}
```

**css:**

```css
#sections .section {display:none;}
#sections.link1 .link1,
#sections.link2 .link2,
#sections.link3 .link3,
#sections.link4 .link4 { display: block; }
```

**html:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler('link1')">Link 1</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler('link2')">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler('link3')">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler('link4')">Link 4</a>

<div id="sections" class="link1">
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="link1div1" class="section link1">11</div>
        <div id="link2div1" class="section link2">21</div>
        <div id="link3div1" class="section link3">31</div>
        <div id="link4div1" class="section link4">41</div>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        <div id="link1div2" class="section link1">12</div>
        <div id="link2div2" class="section link2">22</div>
        <div id="link3div2" class="section link3">32</div>
        <div id="link4div2" class="section link4">42</div>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
        <div id="link1div3" class="section link1">13</div>
        <div id="link2div3" class="section link2">23</div>
        <div id="link3div3" class="section link3">33</div>
        <div id="link4div3" class="section link4">43</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @tborychowski - so simple and far preferable to extraneous JS! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason only one of those is showing is because when you run toggle visibility youre getting every element with the class `section` then toggling them all off except for the ONE that is called into the function. So when your onclick is done running youve turned on the first two then turned them off when you call the last one.

A simple fix would be to give each div in the big div a classname determining the link.

```
<div id=“div3”>
   <div id=“link1div3” class=“section link1”></div>
   <div id=“link2div3” class=“section link2”></div>
   <div id=“link3div3” class=“section link3”></div>
   <div id=“link4div3” class=“section link4”></div>
</div>
```

Do the same for the other divs. Then your links be like this ....

```
<a href=“#” onclick=“togglevisibility(‘link1’);>Link 1 </a>
```

Change your javascript to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleVisibility(selectedClass) {
     var turnOn = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedClass');
     var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
     for(var i=0; i<section.length; i++) { //this for loop hides all the divs
        section[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
     for(var i=0; i<turnOn.length; i++) { // this for loop shows the divs 
        turnOn[i].style.display = 'block'; // with the link1 class
     }
}
</script>
```

This solution if it works (I havent been able to test) will also keep something on the page at all times which I saw you mentioned in bold in your post.