# Javascript: Toggle div visibility in two steps

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, visibility

This question maybe stupid for many here. I have a bunch of divs and want to make them appear/disappear on click with special behaviour:

On-load state: all divs visible

1. click: all divs disappear, except for the one that was selected when clicking
2. to n-th click: toggle visibility for the div that was selected when clicking

What I've got so far:

```js
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
            else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        }

  function toggle_class(id) {
            var thisElem = document.getElementById(id);
            var invisible = "invisible";
            var visible = "visible";
            var classes = thisElem.classList;
            if (classes == invisible) {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
            }
            else {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
            }
        }
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
 <li id='1-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_visibility('1'); toggle_class('1-i');">Toggle DIV #1</a></li>
 <li id='2-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_visibility('2'); toggle_class('2-i');">Toggle DIV #2</a></li>
 <li id='3-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_visibility('3'); toggle_class('3-i');">Toggle DIV #3</a></li>
 <li id='4-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_visibility('4'); toggle_class('4-i');">Toggle DIV #4</a></li>
</ul>


<div id='1' style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #1</h3></div>
<div id='2' style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #2</h3></div>
<div id='3' style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #3</h3></div>
<div id='4' style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #4</h3></div>
```

This code shows all divs on page-load, then toggles visibility for the selected div on click. So on first click only the selected div will disappear with all others staying still visible - the opposite of what I want. Though from second click on, this behaviour is the desired one.

I have found similar other threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407261/toggle-visibility-multiple-divs-javascript)), but their issues seem to add complexity I'd like to avoid.

Thanks a lot for your help!

---

Edit: 
Now I tried to update **function toggle_class(id) {** following Arun P Johny's example:

```js
        var firstrun = true;

        function toggle_class(id) {
            var thisElem = document.getElementById(id);
            var invisible = "invisible";
            var visible = "visible";
            if (thisElem.className == 'invisible' && !firstrun) {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
            } else {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
            }
            if (firstrun) {
                var children = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    if (children[i].id != id) {
                        children[i].className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
                    }
                }
            }
            firstrun = false;
        }
```

The result is somewhat confusing: On first click, the selected element changes its class to *invisible* (which I do understand, since the script tries to replace the class *visible* with *invisible* for all elements). So this is not the behaviour I want, the clicked element is supposed to keep the class *visible* (until it is clicked again, since this is when the div disappears).

And the even more confusing part to me: Not all other elements change their class to *invisible*, but only every second element.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try adding a class to your divs.  Then on click, hide all divs by the class.  Then follow by showing the one related to the option clicked.

Comment: what is the browser compatibility you are looking for

Comment: Compatibility as wide as possible without putting exceptions for all old IE versions. :-)

Comment: Any ideas on the edited part?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to assign a class to all the toggled div elements and use them to fetch and hide them

```
<div id='1' class="toggle" style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #1</h3></div>
<div id='2' class="toggle" style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #2</h3></div>
<div id='3' class="toggle" style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #3</h3></div>
<div id='4' class="toggle" style='display: block;'><h3>DIV #4</h3></div>
```

then

```
var first = true;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id), toggle;
    if (e.style.display == 'block' && !first) {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        var children = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
        for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
            if(children[i].id != id){
                children[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    first = false;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yxod9wm2/)

---

Using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), you may have to include a [shim to support older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#wrapper)

```
<div id='1' class="toggle"><h3>DIV #1</h3></div>
<div id='2' class="toggle"><h3>DIV #2</h3></div>
<div id='3' class="toggle"><h3>DIV #3</h3></div>
<div id='4' class="toggle"><h3>DIV #4</h3></div>
```

then

```
var first = true;

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var thisElem = document.getElementById(id);
    var classes = thisElem.classList;
    if (classes.contains('hidden') || first) {
        classes.remove('hidden');
        var children = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (children[i].id != id) {
                children[i].classList.add('hidden');
                console.log('x')
            }
        }
    } else {
        classes.add('hidden');
    }
    first = false;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yxod9wm2/3/)

Comment: Hi Arun P Johny,
thanks for the script and the attempt to support old browsers as well! Unfortunately, my description of the behaviour from click #2 to click #n was not clear and led to a misunderstanding. Sorry for that! What I meant was: 
All divs except for one disappear on 1st click. On 2nd click (and 3rd, nth), the - now invisble - divs appear additionally to the one selected on 1st click.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I tried to add this functionality myself, but failed since I have very few js experience. Your solution with toggling the _display:_ value from _none_ to _block_ is pretty neat!

Comment: Just edited the opening post since I experienced problems when updating another function following your example.

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: I use the class _invisible_ to grey out the corresponding items in the <ul>-list to all divs that were clicked away with _toggle_visibility()_: You click on DIV #1, all other divs disappear - and the list items "Toggle DIV #2", "Toggle DIV #3" and "Toggle DIV #4" shall change their class to _invisible_.

Comment: (... and of course change back to _visible_ once you select one of them again.)

Answer (score 0):

Overly simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/9ref3cf2/

HTML

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li data-id="1">Toggle DIV #1</li>
    <li data-id="2">Toggle DIV #2</li>
    <li data-id="3">Toggle DIV #3</li>
    <li data-id='4'>Toggle DIV #4</li>
</ul>

<div data-id='1' class="listBlock"><h3>DIV #1</h3></div>
<div data-id='2' class="listBlock"><h3>DIV #2</h3></div>
<div data-id='3' class="listBlock"><h3>DIV #3</h3></div>
<div data-id='4' class="listBlock"><h3>DIV #4</h3></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleListBlocks() {
    $('.listBlock').hide();
    $('.listBlock[data-id='+ $(this).data('id') +']').show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list>li').click(toggleListBlocks);
});
```

Comment: Hi Taplar, thanks for this super-simplified version! I'm impressed how few code lines can provide the functionality! As I just put in the comment on Arun P Johny's solution, I made a mistake when describing the needed behaviour. What do I need to add to the code to make an invisible div visible on click _in addition_ to all visible divs at that time?

Comment: Oh, just got exactly what I needed.